Framing material for a pickup bed topper for overlanding
and thanks in advance for your comments. I am looking for a light weight framing solution, for a diy truck bed topper to use while overlanding.
The frame needs to hold about 300lbs dynamic load while driving (rooftop tent, solar panels and maybe a gear box while at highway speeds), and about 800lbs while the truck is stationary. Is there such material outside of structural steel? I was hoping for something that doesn’t require welding to put together and to use hdpe for cladding rather than plywood.
